# how to detect 64bit platform by script

Tags: inno-setup

is there code to detect 64 platform  e.g.

```
if X86 then ...
if X64 then ...
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Yes.

Use

```
if IsWin64 then
  // Do sth
else
  // Do sth else
```

There is also a `Is64BitInstallMode` function. Indeed, a 32-bit setup can run on a 64-bit OS. Hence, `Is64BitInstallMode` implies `IsWin64`, but `IsWin64` does not imply `Is64BitInstallMode`.

Answer (score 52):

If you want to throw a check on whether to drop or run a file you can also throw a check on the call.

```
Check: IsWin64;
```

or even

```
Check: "not IsWin64";
```

This allows a quick and easy way to compile 32-bit & 64-bit application installers into one package, but only run the specific one.

EDIT: To expand a little further for those that might be searching for this, I wanted to follow up.

For example, if you want to only allow certain files to be copied down by the installer you could do the following:

```
[Files]
Source: "MyProg-x64.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Check: IsWin64;
Source: "MyProg-x86.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Check: "not IsWin64";
```

Adapted from source: http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptcheck