# how to check my pc is 32-bit (or)64-bit operation system using InnoSetup?and how can i check .net framework 4.5 is installed in my pc using innosetup?

Tags: inno-setup

I want to check whether my pc is 32 bit (or)64 bit operating system using inno setup.
And how can i check whether .net framework 4.5  is installed in my pc? if not installed how to give .net framework 4.5 package from my setup using innosetup?
And how to install .net framework 4.5 from web using innosetup?

Regards,
Lokesh.J

Comment: Hello Lokesh and welcome to StackOverflow. Please only ask one question per question, asking a new question if you have a second question. Windows Bitness and installing .NET are two unrelated tasks so should be separate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Detect OS is 32/64 Bit look at this.
[how to detect 64bit platform by script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3618049/how-to-detect-64bit-platform-by-script).

To check what .NET Version is installed try use this script.
http://www.kynosarges.org/DotNetVersion.html

.NET Installer you can look at this.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20868/NET-Framework-1-1-2-0-3-5-Installer-for-InnoSetup

Just search on Google and you will find all the answers you need. Hope this helps.