# Packing multiple exe files in Inno setup and install x64 or x86 version exe depending on OS

Tags: visual-studio-2015, inno-setup, exe, setup-project

I want to execute multiple exe files. I have 3 exe files:

**1. XYZTool.exe**

**2. vcredst_x86** (Visual Studio Redistributable 2015)

**3. vcredst_x64** (Visual Studio Redistributable 2015)

When XYZTool.exe is run, the supported vcredst( x64 or x86) should run and installed successfully and then the installation of XYZTool should resume and install successfully.

Comment: So the `XYZTool.exe` is an installer? Or application that is installer by your Inno Setup installer?

Comment: XYZTool.exe is a exe file generated by VS 2015 in release mode

Comment: So what sense makes *"When XYZTool.exe is run, the supported vcredst( x64 or x86) should run"*? Shouldn't it be *"**Before** XYZTool.exe is run"*? Or *"When XYZTool.exe is **installed**"*?

Comment: Let me clear it. Earlier I had XYZTool.exe and other files packed into one executable itself, as i never had issues with dlls. But now the VS 2015 exe can't be run on PCs which don't have those dlls. The only way to ensure dlls are added to the target PC is installing vcredst.  Even without packing vcredst the application will be installed but cannot be run (It gives an error dll is missing) . Hence i need to install vcredst before running the XYZTool application.

Comment: This can be ensured also by installing supported vcredst first and then XYZTool. You might be suggesting the same

Comment: I will try it. Thanks for the help

Comment: If it does, please accept the duplicate.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/3618049/850848

Comment: Though, are you really sure you want that? If your application is 32-bit (just a guess), you need 32-bit redistributables, no matter what platform the target system uses, don't you?

Comment: Yes. I found that solution. I will add the answer. Thank you